# ASP Classic page inserts text to MSSQL server 2008 in the wrong charset

Tags: sql-server, encoding, vbscript, asp-classic, hebrew

i recently switched a ASP Classic website from Windows 2003 server to Windows 2008 R2 server and i'm having trouble with encoding in my website

the page code is set to 1255(Hebrew) and it's displaying the data correctly when i read from the DB but when i update/insert the text is saved as windows-1252.
i know this because when i change the page code to 1252 the data from the DB that was updated/inserted is the only data the is displayed correctly
even when i "upsert" data with the 'N' prefix the data is inserted incorrectly

what i have\done so far:

1. the server has hebrew installed and support for non-unicode programs is set to hebrew
2. the MSSQL instance collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS, so goes to the Database and each nvarchar,ntext column in the database.
3. IIS ASP default page code is 1255, script language is VBScript.

anyone know what i can do next?

Answer (score 0):

These days there's no reason not to use utf-8 for everything, which means setting  codepage to 65001, and using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

There's more detail here

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

If you use html forms and asp to input data this may result in text displaying correctly in web pages, but not looking anything like Hebrew in your SQL Server manager tool.  If that is an issue then maybe an expert with SQL Server can finish this answer

Comment: Thanks John. as i can relate to your advise i won't really take it into action as i don't want to continue the development in asp classic but only want the website to work.